# how to make a column width size fixed in datagridview asp?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i have this column in a datagridview on aspx page

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Observacion">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblOrderID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Observacion") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="200px" Wrap="False" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have set up the itemstyle with and wrap to false, but anyways the width columns grows the the data is too long. 
i just want to change the height of the column not the width. Here us the complete code of the datagridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <columns>
        <asp:boundfield datafield="ID_OBSERVACION" visible="False" />
        <asp:boundfield datafield="AUTOR" headertext="Autor" />
        <asp:boundfield datafield="FECHA" headertext="Fecha" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Observacion">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblOrderID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Observacion") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="200px" Wrap="False" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </columns>

    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" Wrap="False" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" Wrap="False" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: It is still not clear what you really want. Prevent from wrapping(fixed height) or a fixed width?

Comment: both, i want a fixes width, but wrapping on height.

Comment: You want no wrap and also a fix width? If so, how do you want to deal with the problem that the user won't see the complete text if it's too long?

Comment: it will wrap vertical not horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the `Width` parameter is not compatible with the `Wrap`
parameter. Without `Width`, the `Wrap=False` part is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap should be set to true so that the browser can wrap the cell contents. However if a single word within the cell is wider than the cell width, the browser would not break it. If that is the case, you may have to use the table-layout: fixed along with column width.